# On integers having a given number of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a nice question for you today =).

For a natural number $ n\geq 2 $, define $ f(n) $ to be the smallest positive integer which has exactly $n$ positive divisors. Show that for any $ k\geq 0 $, the number $ f(2^{k}) $ divides the number $ f(2^{k+1}) $